# An exception of BufferNotEmpty from PHPZip

Tags: php, mpdf, cakephp-3.2, php-ziparchive

I got this exception, but there's no other useful details. I'm using mpdf6.1.0, and PHPZip2.0.8 . My code s like below.

```
$zip = new Zip();
$mpdf = null;
foreach ($htmlArr as $name=>$html) {
    if ($mpdf === null) {
        $mpdf = initializePdf();
    }
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $zip->addFile($mpdf->Output('', 'S'), $name, microtime());
    $mpdf = null;
}
$zip->sendZip('test.zip', "application/zip", 'test.zip');
```

The initializePdf function is like below.

```
function initializePdf() {
    $mpdf = new mPDF('CJK', 'A4', '12px', '', 10, 10, 5, 5);
    $mpdf->useAdobeCJK = true;
    $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
    $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->autoMarginPadding = 1;
    $mpdf->cropMarkLength = 0;
    $mpdf->autoPageBreak = true;

    return $mpdf;
}
```

The htmlArr is perfectly fine. I've checked it several times. And I can output PDF file at the $zip->addFile line. But when I change to output stream in zip file. It occurs an BufferNotEmpty Exception. Please help me.
I'm Using CakePHP3.2.3 . It works perfectly fine when I isolate the code into a simple php file. But I don't know why I get the exception. And the debug page shows me the message like this

```
Unable to send 'test.zip'. Output buffer contains the following text (typically warning or errors):
```

Comment: I'm Using CakePHP3.2.3 . It works perfectly fine when I isolate the code into a simple php file. But I don't know why I get the exception. And the debug page shows me the message like this

Answer (score 0):

I find out that there's a single space in the output buffer. That's why the error message looks so strang. PHPZip chose to stop because of it detected that the buffer is not empty. I put one line before sendZip to clean the output buffer like below.

```
$zip = new Zip();
$mpdf = null;
foreach ($htmlArr as $name=>$html) {
    if ($mpdf === null) {
        $mpdf = initializePdf();
    }
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $zip->addFile($mpdf->Output('', 'S'), $name, microtime());
    $mpdf = null;
}
// clean buffer
ob_clean();
// send zip stream to browser
$zip->sendZip('test.zip', "application/zip", 'test.zip');
```

Comment: I would suggest to check your PHP source files instead, you may have a whitespace before `<?php` somewhere. This can cause problems in other situations too, like when sending headers or cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check it.

Comment: I'm using the cakephp-codesniffer standard for my code. Cake would told me if there's any unexpected whitespace. And my git hook will stop me from pushing my code to the cloud. Still I checked every file which created by my team. And there's no unexpected whitespace before or after the php open tag.

Comment: Still cannot find where this single space came from.